# DHCP request packet in c#

Tags: c#, dhcp

hi
how can i send a dhcp request/discovery packet using c# to locate dhcp server any idea or snippet

Answer (score 1):

See the [P/Invoke.net - dhcpsapi](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/dhcpsapi.DhcpGetClientInfo) in windows. There are also docs about the DHCP APIs on windows [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363383%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: This looks like it only works with client side info or windows DHCP servers.

Comment: basically i want to discover the dhcp server on lan in c#

Answer (score 0):

Grab Wiresharp and the DHCP RFCs

- [DHCP on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DHCP)
- [Wireshark (packet sniffer)](http://www.wireshark.org/)
- [RFC2131 - Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (RFC 2131)](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2131.html)
- [RFC2132 - DHCP Options and BOOTP Vendor Extensions (RFC 2132)](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2132.html)