# How to get DHCP information in C#?

Tags: c#, dhcp

I would like to get DHCP Option 15 information in C#. I do not want to call through dhcpsapi.dll though, because I don't want to be limited to just Windows DHCP servers. Is there some other way to get DHCP information through C# or am I going to have to handcode this?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986982/dhcp-request-packet-in-c, which suggests you may need to code it yourself to the RFCs

Comment: Here is an example in Power Shell http://www.indented.co.uk/index.php/2010/02/17/dhcp-discovery/, that you could convert to C#.

Comment: Do you want to know the active domainname (option 15) on your local machine, or do you want to query dhcp servers on the network to see what they provide?

Comment: updated powershell link: https://www.indented.co.uk/dhcp-discovery/ @Zachary

Answer (score 0):

You can use WMI and the Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration class.
One of the available fields returned is DNSHostName which seems to be DHCP option 15.

```
ManagementObjectSearcher query = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE IPEnabled = 'TRUE'") ;
ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = query.Get();
foreach( ManagementObject mo in queryCollection )
{
    string dnsName = (string[])mo["DNSHostName"];
    Console.WriteLine("IP Address: {0}", ipaddress);
}
```