# How to get DHCP Option Info from Windows 7 using .net 3.5 C#

Tags: c#, windows-7, .net-3.5, dhcp

I am looking for a way to read the custom DHCP options stored on a Windows 7 DHCP Client using .net 3.5 C#, specifically a WPF application.

I'm looking to pass an IP addess as a string in one of the DHCP Option fields (still looking into which option number to use recomendations welcome)

The DHCP server will be a Windows 2008 R2 server

I would like to use managed code if at all possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650540/how-to-get-dhcp-information-in-c

Comment: @M.Babcock It's not a duplicate, that question is only for DHCP Option 15 and they're using the WMI DNSHostName entry to get that information and that may just happen to be the same rather than actually getting DHCP Option 15. I am looking to get a variety of DHCP Options that were sent using DHCP.

Comment: Ok so it isn't a duplicate, but their solution sounds like it should be able to apply to your situation as well (just use a different index than "DNSHostName").

Comment: @M.Babcock I am hopeing somone can confirm or deny that and perhaps provide a link to a table that shows the mapping for options to WMI indexs. After a decent bit of searching and looking around on the internet I have not found much information on any mapping between the two, which lead to me asking the question here.